# How to setup Codekit to refresh pages when I updated my mako files?

Tags: mako, livereload, codekit

Hi so I'm working in PyCharm using the Pyramid Python framework and using the template system [Mako](http://www.makotemplates.org/), .mak files.

With [LiveReload](http://livereload.com/) I was able to add the .mak file extensions and it was able to refresh the pages I was working on.

I'm not sure how to do that with **[Codekit](http://incident57.com/codekit/)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just figured it out, in preferences > languages I added `mak`

Then back in preferences > general I have to make sure that my localhost / ip had to be included in the Auto-reload browsers section.

[image]